# CURL paypal Patch Fails

Tags: curl, paypal

Here's my patch:

```
C:\Windows\System32>curl -v -X PATCH https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/6HA17506GU734870J/ -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer A21AAJbK58GoF7Usyp4eTiaddlYJyHxqOueCQ5na3yajClJatrVJ6sVaNy2CWCELbXjKcpcgM3JkSnFVLxcXEAwF5vEvh88Ew" -d '[{"op":"replace","path":"/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/amount","value":{"currency_code":"CAD","value":"3.45"}}]'


{"name":"INVALID_REQUEST","message":"Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.","debug_id":"1548458b4a72c","details":[{"location":"body","issue":"MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON","description":"The request JSON is not well formed."}],"links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON","rel":"information_link","encType":"application/json"}]}* Connection #0 to host api.sandbox.paypal.com left intact
```

Do I need to escape all of the control characters?  Not sure why this call is failing, my create, get details, approve, and completed calls all work.  Just not this update call.

I've tried to re-structure the object going into the patch body multiple times.
I've escaped the path variable chars as well.  Though not 100% on these.`

Comment: You need to escape the single quotes that are within the `-d '...'` string, try `reference_id==\'default\'`

Comment: Hi Preston, thanks very much for your help! I managed to get it working with the following code just a few minutes ago: [{"op":"replace","path":"/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'","value":{"amount":{"currency_code":"CAD","value":"1","breakdown":{"item_total":{"currency_code":"CAD","value":"1"}}},"invoice_id":"123456","items":[{"name":" Shampoo","unit_amount":{"currency_code":"CAD","value":"1"},"quantity":"1","sku":"132"},{"name":"Shipping costs","unit_amount":{"currency_code":"CAD","value":"0"},"quantity":"1"}]}}]. Cheers!